# Estimated protein size using CDs data

Tags: bioinformatics, dna, proteins, statistics, biostatistics

The number of amino acids in a protein is important to predict their size. I used coding DNA sequence (CDs) to predict the average of the protein size of *E.coli k12* from a sample provided by the `seqinr` R package. The size of each sequence is stored in variable `x`. 
I used two histograms to fit the distribution of this variable and their logarithm.

[image]
[image]

I suggest that the log linear distribution is more reasonable.The average E can be calculated then:

```
E1=mean(x)/3

E2=exp(mean(log(x)))/3
```

- Which average do I have to use?
- Is there a correlation between the base composition and the predicted average?

Comment: You seem to have two questions but I don't really understand them. Here is my try to rephrase your questions. 1) `What standard theoretical distribution best fit the observed distribution?` This is a question of statistics, not biology. 2) `Is there a correlation between GC skew and protein length?` This question has little to do with the rest of the post.

Comment: *`Which average do I have to use?`* They are both the same, since you're using the exact same data. It's only the *presentation* that's different, as you're comparing a linear plot to a log plot.

Comment: @MattDMo Not necessarily. OP might want average log weight which is not the same as log of average weight.

Comment: Can you elaborate your question? I am having a hard time understanding what you are exactly asking for.